# VB.NET SQL Display Attendance Monthly , Yearly

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to display all the Employee's Attendance Date As a Monthly Report.
So my database will be something like this.

[image]

How can i display them like this, all the month will be calculated. Thanks

[image]

I have tried using this code and it only return 1 result, thanks

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID ,COUNT( DISTINCT checkinDate) As April FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE checkinDate BETWEEN '4/1/2018' AND '4/30/2018'  GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID
```

Comment: do u want a vb.net solution ? and please clarify your needs a bit more clearly ... it is better to give a clear example and an expected result :)

Comment: @zackraiyan 
Thanks, i have edited the post and give the expected results i want to achieve  at the second picture
I just want the queries needed for me to achieve the results through SQL query

Comment: i am posting an answer...hope it hhelps you

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I added the answer but i am adding some side-notes too...Be a bit patient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quiet simple.First store the employee ids in a list.

```
 Dim employeeList as New List(of String)

 Dim con as New SqlConnection("connection string her")
 Dim cmd as New SqlCommand("Select employeeID from tableName",con)
 Dim dr as new SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
 While dr.read
   employeeList.Add(dr(0).ToString)
 End while

'Make sure to remove duplicates from the list'

 employeeList=employeeList.Distinct.ToList()
```

Create a class that handles the employeeId,Attendence count and month names

```
 Public class employees
  Public id as String
  Public month as String
  Public atCount as Integer
 End class
```

Now you can use the ids from the list and get the the count of the attendence of each employeeId,also make sure to create a list of the class we just made.

```
  Dim resultList as New List(of employees)  'We are creating the list to hold the records of each employee'

  Private sub addData()

   Dim month as Integer = 1  
   Dim year as Integer = 2014   'I created two variables which would later be used in the sql statements and furthermore.'

   Dim cmd as New SqlCommand("Select * from tablename Where employeeId=@empid,MONTH(checkinDate) = " + month + " AND YEAR(checkinDate) =" + year + "" , con)  'Here we use the MONTH(date) and YEAR function of SQL'


   cmd.Parameters.Add("@empid",sqlDbType.VarChar)
   Dim dr as SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
   For Each id in employeeList  'Here we iterate through the list'
    cmd.Parameters(0).Value = id
    While dr.read 
     Dim emp as New employees
     emp.id = id
     emp.month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month)
     emp.atCount = emp.atCount + 1  'Here we increase the count of attendence for each record that exisits'


     resultList.Add(emp)  'Finally we add the data to the list'
    End While
   dr.Close()
   If not month = 12 Then  
    month = month + 1   'Firstly we check if our "month" value exceeded 12,if it did, we count one more year , if not , we count one more month'
   Else
    year = year + 1
    month = 1
   End if        
   Next
 End sub
```

Now you have a list..you can save it's data to the database :

```
 Dim cmd as new SqlCommand("Insert Into tableName(empId,MonthName,Count)VALUES(@eid,@mname,@count)")
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@eid",sqlDbType.Varchar)
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@mname",sqlDbType.Varchar)
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@count",sqlDbType.Int)

 For Each employee in resultList  'We iterate through our final list now'


   cmd.Parameters(0).Value = employee.id
   cmd.Parameters(1).Value = employee.month
   cmd.Parameters(2).Value = employee.atCount
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

 Next

 'Make sure you close the connection when all is done :)'
   con.Close
```

Or, if you simply want to display the final list in a datagridview,consider the below code snippet :

```
For Each employee in resultList

Dim row As DataGridViewRow = CType(dgvw1.Rows(0).Clone(), DataGridViewRow)
row.Cells(0).Value = employee.id
row.Cells(1).Value = employee.month
row.Cells(2).Value = employee.atCount
dgvw1.Rows.Add(row)

Next
```

Hope this helps and enriches your knowledge :)

Comment: Thanks , but i actually just want to just display all the data in SQL to a DataGridView

Comment: didn't get that ? you don't want to insert in the database rather just want to show in a datagridview ?

Comment: @ zack raiyan Thanks , Yes , i just wanted to show all my data in DataGridView by getting all the data from database , display it according to all the months

Comment: re-check my answer :) and make sure to mark it as answer if it helped :)